# Python (Heroku): Flask buttons not working

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, heroku, flask

Please excuse the poor title, do suggest something better if you have any ideas. Anyway, recently I've been playing with both Heroku and Flask yet have come across an adversity - my buttons aren't working! You can view the page [here.](https://mirrordown.herokuapp.com)

The code is as follows;

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    userkey = request.form['username']
    passkey = request.form['password']
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))


@app.route('/createAccount', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createAccount():
    userkey = request.form['username']
    passkey = request.form['password']
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

The HTML reads;

```
<form id="login" action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Userkey" required />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Passkey" required />
  <button type="submit" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #33aa33, #288228);"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <form action="{{ url_for('createAccount') }}" method="post">
    <button><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  </form>
</form>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I'm not getting any feedback at all, with nothing in Heroku logs - not that I expected anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is not linked to the from. You need something like this:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('createAccount') }}" method="post" id="form1">

</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to make a difference for me. Do I need to update my Python code at all?

Comment: I checked your code, and I saw some javascript disabling action of your form: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });`

Comment: My mistake. I had that to ensure the form wouldn't do its default redirect behaviour, the thought never came to my mind that I wouldn't need it anymore.